# Prisma client extensions - calling async functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

I'm trying to use the new Prisma client extensions with an async function. Essentially, I need to call a function in the result that gets some external values and adds them to a custom column. In the example below, standard (non async)function work, but I can't get async functions to work.

UPDATE - Simplified example code

```js
async function carl() {
  return "carl is cool!"
}

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends({
  result: {
    user: {
      // Add a computed field called `nameAndAge` to the user
      nameAndAge: {
        needs: {
          name: true,
          age: true,
          country: true,
        },
        compute(user) {
          return `${user.name} (${user.age}y), ${user.country}` + await carl();
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

const user = await prisma.user.findFirst();
console.log(user);
```